# Printing a star pattern in swift using stride function

Tags: swift

Right now i am trying to print following star pattern using swift 4.

```
1
12
123
1234
```

For this i have taken below approach.

```
for i in stride(from: 1, to: 5, by: 1) {
   // prints from 1 to 4
    for j in stride(from: 1, to: i, by: 1) {
          print(j, separator: "", terminator: "")
    }
    print("*\n")
}
```

But right now this will print below output.

```
*

1*

12*

123*
```

Any way to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want

```
1
12
123
1234

for i in 1..<5 { // or for i in stride(from: 1, to: 5, by: 1) {
    for j in 1...i { // for j in stride(from: 1, through: i, by: 1) {
        print(j, terminator: "")
    }
    print("")
}
```

If you want

```
*
**
***
****

for i in 1..<5 {
    for _ in 1...i {
        print("*", terminator: "")
    }
    print("")
}
```

Comment: Thanks vadian Using only for..in loop i am also able to do it , but i am wondering using stride function wheather it is doable or not.

Comment: In this case there is no benefit using stride because the type is `Int` and the increment is 1. I updated the answer with the proper `stride` syntax. Note the difference `to` and `through`.

Answer (score 13):

**Here are some logical pattern in swift 4** ,

```
    0
   01
  012
 0123
01234

for i in  0...4{

    for j in stride(from: 4, to: i, by: -1){
        print( terminator : " ")
    }
    for k in 0...i{
        print(k,terminator : "")
    }
    print(" ")
}

54321
5432
543
54
5

for i in stride(from: 0, to: 5, by: 1){

    for j in stride(from: 5, to: i, by: -1){
        print(j , terminator : "")
    }
    print(" ")

}
5
5 4
5 4 3
5 4 3 2
5 4 3 2 1


for i in stride(from: 5, to: 0, by: -1)
{

    for j in stride(from: 5, to: i-1, by: -1){

      print(j , terminator : "")
    }
    print(" ")
}
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4
1 2 3
1 2
1

for i in stride(from: 5, to: 0, by: -1)
{
    for j in 1...i{
        print(j, terminator : "")
    }
    print(" ")
}
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15

var value = 0
for i in 1...5 {

    for j in 1...i{
        value = value + 1
        print(value,terminator : "")
    }
    print(" ")
}
1
2 1
3 2 1
4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1

for i in 1...5{

    for j in 1...i{

    print(i+1 - j , terminator : "")
    }
    print(" ")
}

for i in 1...5{
    for j in stride(from: i, to: 0, by: -1){
        print(j, terminator : "")
    }
    print(" ")
}
1
2 7
3 8 13
4 9 14 19
5 10 15 20 25

var value = 0
for i in 1...5{

    for j in 1...i{
        if j != 1{
            value = value + 5
        }
        else{
            value = i
        }
        print(value , terminator : " ")
    }
    print(" ")
}

for i in 1...5{
    var temp = i
    for j in 0...i{
        print(temp , terminator : " ")
        temp = temp + 5
    }
    print(" ")

}
1
1 2 1
1 2 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1

var value = 1
for i in 1...5{

    for j in 1...i{
         print(j,terminator : "")
    }

        for k in 1..<i{
        print(i-k,terminator : "")
    }
print(" ")
}


1 2 3 4 5
 1 2 3 4
  1 2 3
   1 2
    1
for i in stride(from: 5, to: 0, by: -1){
    for k in stride(from: 5, to: i, by: -1) {
        print(terminator : " ")
    }
        for j in stride(from: 1, to: i+1, by: 1){
           print("*",terminator : " ")
    }


    print(" ")
}

1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1


for i in 1...5{
    for j in stride(from: 5, to: i, by: -1){
        print(i,terminator : "")
    }
    var temp = 1

    for k in 1...i{
        print(temp,terminator : "")
         temp = temp * (i - k) / (k);
    }
    print(" ")
}
    1
   1 2
  1 2 3
 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
 1 2 3 4
  1 2 3
   1 2
    1


for i in 1...5{
    for k in stride(from: 5, to: i, by: -1) {
        print(terminator : " ")
    }

    for j in 1...i{
        print(j,terminator : " ")
    }
    print(" ")
}
for i in stride(from: 5, to: 0, by: -1){
    for k in stride(from: 5, to: i-1, by: -1) {
        print(terminator : " ")
    }
        for j in stride(from: 1, to: i, by: 1){
           print(j,terminator : " ")
    }
  print(" ")
}
12345
2345
345
45
5
5
45
345
2345
12345


for i in 1...5{

    for j in stride(from: i, to: 6, by: 1){
        print(j , terminator : "")
    }

    print(" ")
}
for i in stride(from: 5, to: 0, by: -1)
{

    for j in stride(from: i, to: 6, by: 1){
        print(j,terminator : "")
    }
    print(" ")
}



1 2 3 4 5
 2 3 4 5
  3 4 5
   4 5
    5
 for i in 1...5{
    for k in 0...i{
        print(terminator : " ")
    }
    for j in stride(from: i, to: 6, by: 1){
        print(j , terminator : " ")
    }

    print(" ")
}


12345
 2345
  345
   45
    5
    5
   45
  345
 2345
12345


for i in 1...5{
    for k in 1...i{
        print(terminator : " ")
    }
    for j in stride(from: i, to: 6, by: 1){
        print(j , terminator : "")
    }

    print(" ")
}
for i in stride(from: 5, to: 0, by: -1)
{
    for k in 1...i{
        print(terminator : " ")
    }
    for j in stride(from: i, to: 6, by: 1){
        print(j,terminator : "")
    }
    print(" ")
}
1 2 3 4 5
 2 3 4 5
  3 4 5
   4 5
    5
    5
   4 5
  3 4 5
 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
for i in 1...5{
    for k in 0...i{
        print(terminator : " ")
    }
    for j in stride(from: i, to: 6, by: 1){
        print(j , terminator : " ")
    }

    print(" ")
}

for i in stride(from: 6, to: 1, by: -1){
    for k in 1...i{
        print(terminator : " ")
    }
    for j in stride(from: i-1, to: 6, by: 1){
        print(j , terminator : " ")
    }

    print(" ")
}
1
1 0
1 0 1
1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1

for i in 0...4{
    for j in 0...i{
        if j % 2 == 0{
        print(1,terminator : " ")
        }
        else{
            print(0,terminator : " ")
        }
    }
    print(" ")

    }

1 0 0 0 0
0 2 0 0 0
0 0 3 0 0
0 0 0 4 0
0 0 0 0 5


for i in 1...5{
    for j in 1...5{

        if j == i{
            print(j,terminator : " ")
        }
        else{
            print(0,terminator : " ")
        }

    }
    print(" ")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info anyone reading the above answers take care of the spaces in the print statment

Answer (score 4):

```
1) Pyramid

                *
               * *
              * * *
             * * * *
            * * * * *

LINK :- 

https://replit.com/@vishakhaagarwa1/DarkorchidSmoothPayware#main.swift

for i in 1...5
{
    for _ in stride(from: 5, to: i, by: -1) 
    {
        print(terminator : " ")
    }

    for _ in 1...i
    {
        print("*",terminator : " ")
    }
    print(" ")
}





2) Right Triangle
*
* *
* * *
* * * *
* * * * *

LINK :- 

https://replit.com/@vishakhaagarwa1/StingyOldApplicationstack#main.swift

var i = 1
var j = 1
for i in i...5
{
  for _ in j...i
  {
     print("*",terminator : "")
  }
  print("")
}



3) Mirrored Right Triangle

        *
      * *
    * * *
  * * * *
* * * * *
LINK :- 

https://replit.com/@vishakhaagarwa1/CookedParallelRobodoc#main.swift

for i in 1...5
{
   for _ in stride (from: 5, to: i, by: -1)
  {
    print(" ",terminator : "")
  }
  for _ in 1...i
  {
     print("*",terminator : "")
  }
 
  print("")
}


4) Diamond

        *
      * * *
    * * * * *
  * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * *
  * * * * * * *
    * * * * *
      * * *
        *

LINK :-

https://replit.com/@vishakhaagarwa1/WarmEmptyDegrees#main.swift






for i in 1...10
{
  if i % 2 != 0
  {
    for _ in stride(from: 10, to: i, by: -1) 
    {
        print(terminator : " ")
    }

    for _ in 1...i
    {
        print("*",terminator : " ")
    }
    print(" ")
  }
}
for i in stride(from: 10, to: 1, by: -1)
{
   if i % 2 != 0
  {
    for _ in stride(from: 10, to: i-1, by: -1) 
    {
        print(terminator : " ")
    }

    for _ in stride(from: 2, to: i, by: 1)
    {
        print("*",terminator : " ")
    }
    print(" ")
  }
}





5) Downward Triangle
* * * * *
* * * *
* * *
* *
*

LINK :- 

https://replit.com/@vishakhaagarwa1/FearlessIndolentByte#main.swift

for i in 1...5
{
  for _ in stride(from: i, to: 6, by: 1)
  {
    print("*",terminator : "")
  }
  print("")
}


6) Right Pascal’s Triangle
*
* *
* * *
* * * *
* * * * *
* * * *
* * *
* *
*
LINK :-

https://replit.com/@vishakhaagarwa1/IndianredNervousPrinter#main.swift

for i in 1...5
{
  for _ in 1...i
  {
     print("*",terminator : "")
  }
 
  print("")
}
for i in 1...4
{
  for _ in stride (from: 5, to: i, by: -1)
  {
     print("*",terminator : "")
  }

  print("")
}


7) Sandglass Pattern

* * * * *
 * * * *
  * * *
   * *
    *
    *
   * *
  * * *
 * * * *
* * * * *

LINK :-

https://replit.com/@vishakhaagarwa1/TangibleDeeppinkWatch#main.swift

for i in 1...5
{
  for _ in 1...i
  {
    print(terminator: " ")
  }
  for _ in stride(from: i, to: 6, by: 1)
  {
    print("*",terminator : " ")
  }
  print("")
}
for i in 1...5
{
    for _ in stride(from: 6, to: i, by: -1) 
    {
        print(terminator : " ")
    }

    for _ in 1...i
    {
        print("*",terminator : " ")
    }
    print(" ")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for  i in 0...5{
  for _ in 0...i{
    print("*", terminator: "")
  }
 print()  }

for i in stride(from: 5, to: 0, by: -1){

  for _ in stride(from: i, to: 0, by: -1){
    print("*",terminator: "")
  }
  print()  }
```

output :

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
var q : String = ""
repeat
{
  print("***** Numerical Patterns *****")
  print("1 for Number Right Triangle.. ")
  print("2 for Sequential Number Right Triangle.. ")
  print("3 for Pascal Number Triangle.. ")
  print("Enter Your Choice :: ")
  guard let index = Int(readLine()!), index > 0 && index < 4 else
  {
    print(" !!!! WArning :: Wrong Selection.......")
    print("\n")
    continue
  } 
  var n: Int
  print("Enter N Number For Pattern :: ")
  let num = readLine()
  if let t2 = Int(num!)
  {
    n = t2
  }
  else
  {
    print("wrong input ! taking default [5]")
    n = 5
  }

  switch index {
    case 1  :
        for i in 1...n
        {
          for j in 1...i
          {
            print(j,terminator: " ")
          }
          print("")
        }
    case 2  :
      var j = 0
      for i in 1...n
      {
        for _ in 1...i
        {
          j = j+1
          print(j,terminator: " ")
        }
        print("")
      }
    case 3  :
        for i in 1...n
      { 
        //print("i==",i)
        for _ in stride(from: n, to: i, by: -1) 
        {
          //print("k==",k)
          print(terminator : " ")
        }
        var no = 1
        for j in 1...i
        {
          //print("j==",j)
          print(no,terminator : " ")
          no = no * (i - j) / (j)

        }
        print(" ")
      }
    default :
        print( "Wrong Input............")
  }
  print("\n")
  print("Do you want to continues [PRESS Y/y] OR CLOSE [PRESS N/n] :: ")
  q = (readLine()!)
  print("\n")
}while(q == "y" || q == "Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

```swift
func starprint(_ int : Int)
{
  for i in 1...int
  {
     print(String.init(repeating: " ", count: int-i)+String.init(repeating: "*", count: i))
  }
}
starprint(6)
```

Comment: That said, Sulaiman, you shouldn't just dump code as an answer. And especially when there are existing answers that have been validated by the community. Can you [edit] your answer to explain what you've done, how it differs from other answers, and why you think this is a better solution? That will be more useful to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in stride(from: 1, to: 6, by: 1) {
   // prints from 1 to 4
    for j in stride(from: 1, to: i, by: 1) {
          print(j, separator: "", terminator: "")
    }
    print("")
}
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score -1):

You can use for loop with below sequencing

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
 
func printLadderNumber(_ n: Int) {
    for i in 1...n {
        for j in 1...i {
            print(j, terminator: "")
        }
        print("", terminator: "\n")// Helps for printing new line
    }
}
printLadderNumber(4)
```

You can find various Star Patterns Question here

https://janeshswift.com/ios/dsa/array/how-to-print-patterns-in-swift/

Answer (score -2):

> ```
> 1.  Pyramid
>
>     1 
>    1 2 
>   1 2 3 
>  1 2 3 4 
>
> for i in 1...4{     
>     for _ in 1...5-i{
>         print(terminator:" ")
>     }
>     for j in 1...i{
>         print(j,terminator:" ")
>     }
>     print("")
> }
>
> 2. Inverted Pyramid
>
>  1 2 3 4 
>   1 2 3 
>    1 2 
>     1 
>
> for i in 1...4{   
>     for _ in 1...i{
>         print(terminator:" ")
>     }
>    
>     for j in 1...5-i{
>         print(j,terminator:" ")
>     }
>     print("")
> }
> ```